# Keep getting errors from apport_python_hook.py

Tags: software-center, python

I keep getting this error message when trying to do any apt-get command, or almost any command in general, it also shows up when I open the terminal. I also cannot open the Software Center and Software Updater. Even when I try to reinstall python to fix the error it gives me this error.. would love any suggestions!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 5, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
ImportError: No module named '__future__'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
    import re
ImportError: No module named 're'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 5, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
ImportError: No module named '__future__'
```